# Get key from hkp server but failed because "unknown pubkey algorithm"

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg, apt-get, apt, gpg-signature

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.

When I ran

```
apt-get update
```

it failed with following error：

```
the following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1C52189C923F6CA9
```

so I ran:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1C52189C923F6CA9
```

to get the pubkey but failed again with the following error:

```
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
1C52189C923F6CA9
gpg: requesting key 923F6CA9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 1C52189C923F6CA9 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver helper general error
gpg: keyserver communications error: unknown pubkey algorithm
gpg: keyserver receive failed: unknown pubkey algorithm
```

I still don't know how to solve it after searching and trying many times.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced with same problem, and I've fix this by check this :

- If your internet connection is behind some Authentication gate or proxy

  **Make sure that you have login to the authentication gate, or export the proxy so the terminal can communicate to the public key server**

UPDATE : Well, the authentication gate is depend on your internet provider. It is used to be a website login page.

Or, you can enter this to use proxy in your terminal :

```
export http_proxy='http://<proxyserveraddress>:<portnumber>'    
export https_proxy='https://<proxyserveraddress>:<portnumber>'
```

Comment: Thanks well that was the issue!

Comment: What is the authentification gate and how can I exprot the proxy ?